# DataGrid row highlighting for dynamic objects

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I’m using the „Xceed Extended WPF Tookit Plus (Complete”) Edition in version 2.4.14475.10340 and the DataGrid of the toolkit in a production software environment.

Currently I’m struggling to get a datarow highlighting to work again.

a.) The data source for the grid has been a standard DataTable, so a custom DataRow style like the following did work for me:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=[IsTrend]}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Because of the dynamic nature of the underlying data, we changed the source type to “ExpandoObject” and use that in its dictionary form to add/remove data entries, which then are mapped to datagrid columns using the field name. After that change the above styling doesn’t work anymore, error see below:

```
Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'ExpandoObject'). BindingExpression:Path=[IsTrend]; DataItem='ExpandoObject' (HashCode=34521593); target element is 'DataRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

b.) As a workaround we changed the style to a custom converter:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HighlightingConverter}}"/>
</Style>,
```

which returns a Brush, depending on the value of the fields of the DataRow item (DataGrid.GetItemFromContainer(row)), so the ExpandoObject.

Now the rows in the datagrid are sometimes colored, but a.) not correctly (wrong line) or b.) loose color after a refresh of the data. It looks like a datarow container is colored and then re-used for new data.

My question(s):

1. Why does it work with the above style in a.), but not if I use a custom converter like in b.)? Which field or path is accessed through using the “[]” sytax?
2. Is there a way to achieve row lighting for a dynamic data source?

/Edit:
The source collections looks like this.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<dynamic> GetDynamicOrders2()
{
    var retVal = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
       dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
       eo.Name = new CellContent("Order" + i);
       eo.IsTrend = new CellContent(i % 2 == 0);
       var converted = (IDictionary<string, object>)eo;
       converted["Number"] = new CellContent(i % 4);
       converted["NumberDouble"] = new CellContent((double)i);
       converted["properties_name_first"] = new CellContent("Name " + i);
       retVal.Add(eo);
    }

    return retVal;
 }
```

A cell object is defined as:

```
public sealed class CellContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private object _value;

  public object Value
  {
     get { return _value; }
     set
     {
        if (Equals(value, _value)) return;
        _value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayValue");
        OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
        OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
     }
  }

  public bool Meta { get; set; }
  public string Format { get; set; }
  public double Threshold { get; set; }

  public string DisplayValue
  {
     get
     {
        return string.Format(string.Format("{{0:{0}}}", Format), Value);
     }
  }

  public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor
  {
     get
     {
        var defaultColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        var valueType = Value.GetType();
        if (valueType != typeof (double)) return defaultColor;
        if (double.IsNaN(Threshold)) return defaultColor;
        return (double)Value >= Threshold ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : defaultColor;
     }
  }

  public SolidColorBrush ForegroundColor
  {
     get
     {
        var defaultColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        var valueType = Value.GetType();
        if (valueType != typeof(double)) return defaultColor;
        // inactive
        if (double.IsNaN(Threshold)) return defaultColor;
        return (double)Value >= Threshold ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) : defaultColor;
     }
  }

  public CellContent(object value, bool meta = false, string format = "", double threshold = double.NaN)
  {
     Value = value;
     Meta = meta;
     Format = format;
     Threshold = threshold;
  }

  private bool Equals(CellContent other)
  {
     return Equals(Value, other.Value);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
     if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
     if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
     return Equals((CellContent)obj);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
     return (Value != null ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
```

}

/Edit2: binding error if I use the explicit path:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsTrend' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsTrend; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'DataRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

/Edit3: Solution.
The whole problem was in the way I added the style. As in the question above I defined the style globally, so it is applied to each single DataRow object in this user control/window. That leads to a datacontext of "MainWindow", which is of course of no greater use here.
I changed the style to (key added, path corrected)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}" x:Key="RowStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrend.Value}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and added a reference from the datagrid like that

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="DataGrid" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}">
```

Done. It works again!

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank in advance,
Nico Ecker

Comment: you have bind the background to Self meaning DataRow. Since DataRow is not refreshed while scrolling, refresh (basically the row container cause of virtualization). If you would be able to provide source collection along with above code then it will be easy to give solution. Or I have to arbitrarily made one. your simple target of solution should be bind a property of source collection type that way row color would work perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment, but I'll add info about the source collection into the original question.

Comment: Check the answer...please.let me know if you face some problem

Comment: I have updated the question again with a solution which consists partly of your work, thanks for that, and my own insights.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you still getting any prob? and what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Let me break it down into three questions:

1. Which field or path is accessed through using the “[]” syntax?

The “[]” syntax is used to access the [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) of an object. Whatever you put between the brackets will be treated as the indexer's argument(s).

2. Why does it work with the above style in a.), but not if I use a custom converter like in b.)?

I'm not sure about the second part of that question - it would require additional investigation, which hopefully will not be necessary. As for why does it work if you use [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) as items source - the data being presented by each row is a [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx), and your trigger binds to it's [`Item[String]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx) indexer. The code-behind equivalent of accessing that data would be like

```
var isTrend = dataRow["IsTrend"];
```

3. Is there a way to achieve row lighting for a dynamic data source?

I'm assuming that when you generate the data you set an `IsTrend` property on your `ExpadoObject`:

```
dataObject.IsTrend = (...);
```

If that's the case, the easiest thing you can do is to set up your binding to access that property rather than use an indexer:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrend}" (...) />
```

The reason why the previous binding does not work is because `ExpandoObject` does not have a public `Item[String]` indexer - it does have one, but it's an explicitly implemented [`IDictionary<String, Object>.Item[String]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674733(v=vs.110).aspx), and therefore is not considered public. It's possible to bind to explicitly implemented interface members in XAML, but it's not that pretty and it would be especially hard because that particular interface is a generic one.

Comment: Thanks for your response, now I clearly understand what is goin on in the DataTable and the dynamic object case.
Unfortunately your solution won't help either (I already tried that explicit pathing), because I get a BindingExpression path error. I have added the data objects (please note that each cell is a complex object itself) and the error to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I've used your `source` and make it work with `DataGrid`. See below code:

***XAML:***

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
    Title="MainWindow"   Height="300" Width="300"        
    xmlns:Interact="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"       
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"       
    >   
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="myStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrend.Value}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}" x:Name="myGrid" RowStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IsTrend" Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrend.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Path=Number.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="properties_name_first" Binding="{Binding Path=properties_name_first.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>                       
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

***Output:***

[image: Gold]

***Suggestion:***

**If you want to remove `.Value` from every binding** you can `override` the `ToString()` method in your `CellContent` class like below:

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
```

and Binding will change like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

***PS:*** Though it has a problem, after removing `.Value` `DataTrigger` is not working. I'm working on that if I found any solution I'll update here.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525107/override-tostring-behave-with-binding)  the solution for above mentioned problem.