# overriding ToString() method, behaves strange with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

see below `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
    Title="MainWindow"   Height="300" Width="300"        
    xmlns:Interact="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"       
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"       
    >   
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="myStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrend.Value}" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>            
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}" x:Name="myGrid" RowStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />               
        </DataGrid.Columns>                       
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

***Source of `DataGrid`***

```
private ObservableCollection<dynamic> GetDynamicOrders2()
{
    var retVal = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
        eo.Name = new CellContent("Order" + i);
        eo.IsTrend = new CellContent(i % 2 == 0);               
        retVal.Add(eo);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

***Class***

```
public sealed class CellContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _value;
    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {                
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");               
        }
    }

    public CellContent(object value)
    {
        Value = value;            
    }             

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;                
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

To remove `.Value` from every binding I `override` `ToString()` method.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

and Binding is changed as:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

***But It's behaving differently for `DataTrigger` and `Column` Binding. Can someone explain why and How? Why is `DataTrigger` not working after the change?***

Comment: Can you explain more about *"to remove `.Value` from every binding I override `ToString()` method"* ? Two-way binding is obviously not able to convert `string` value back.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if ToString throws an exception because Value is null or Value's ToString implementation throws an exception. You should have information in your output window

Comment: Don't use `ToString` to do stuff like this, as already mentioned you also break two-way binding.

Comment: @Sinatr you are probably right, but I was more concerned about why Binding and Datatrigger behaving differently...? while posting the question...

Comment: @nkoniishvt no it's not..... when an object is defined in binding it will be resolved as primitive type if it is, else it will resolved after applting ToString() method... and that why I overrode the method and was curious not getting expected result

Comment: @H.B. yes, thanks, I'll take care where i require two way binding... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

`DataGridTextColumn` takes a `CellContent` instance and calls `ToString()` to display it. It displays `Value`, but without `.Value` in the path edits in datagrid cells are not applied.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrend}" Value="True" >
```

`DataTrigger` takes a `CellContent` instance and calls `Equals()` with parameter `"True"`. But CellContent object is not equal to `"True"`.

if I override `Equals`, DataTrigger works

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Value.ToString() == (string) obj;
}
```